# PLSQL is it possible to update a table column on a certain date?

Tags: plsql

I have this table :

```
penalities(player,dateofpenality,penalityDays,status)
```

Based on certain criteria a player is added to this table where the status goes to 'yes'. I want his status to change to 'no' jusrt after the penality period (=penalityDays) is gone.

I thought of a trigger on date but I couldn't find it in plsql.
Please note that I don't want to delete the player as I need the history .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to schedule a background job which kicks off once a day.

Write a simple stored procedure to apply the change of status:

```
create or replace procedure update_penalty_status as
begin

    update penalties
    set status = 'no'
    where sysdate >= dateofpenality + penalityDays
    and status = 'yes';

    commit;

end update_penalty_status;
```

Then submit a job to run once a day. This uses DBMS_SCHEDULER (available since 10g) rather than the older DBMS_JOB.

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
       job_name             => 'your_schema.my_job1',
       job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
       job_action           => 'BEGIN update_penalty_status; END;',
       start_date           => trunc(sysdate)+1,
       repeat_interval      => 'FREQ=DAILY'
       enabled              =>  TRUE,
       comments             => 'Revoke expired penalties');
END;
/
```

Note that you will need the CREATE JOB privilege to do this. You may need to ask your DBA for help and guidance. Normally I would link to the Oracle documentation at this point, but I think [the Oracle-Base article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/scheduler-10g) is a friendlier place to start.

Comment: Thanks ! it possible to deny access on the penalities table on a certain date?as triggers don't work on select

Comment: @clorzs - that's an entirely different question. So please ask it as such. Include pertinent details, such as the definition of "certain date".